# Qt 5 for ROS melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, qt5, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering about the proper way to get Qt 5 for ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. I searched for hours but couldn't find any recent tutorials. Last year, I developed [this package](https://github.com/jstiefel/KinematicsGUI_ROS) where I used catkin_create_qt_pkg with qt_create and depending on qt_build and libqt4-dev. Since these packages are not available for ROS melodic, I can not compile the package anymore.

I've found and installed the following package: [qt_gui](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_gui), but without any hint what it does. I assume the qt_gui_cpp package installs Qt 5 and creates the bindings. Can someone give me an overview of what is needed and what these packages do? Is there a recent example for the package.xml and CMakeLists out there? I assume the source code is the same.

I installed the ROS Qt Creator Plug-in 4.9.2, but I assume this does just install a "ROS-ready" IDE without any Qt libraries, right?

I'm also wondering about the differences between ros-melodic-qt-gui, ros-melodic-libqt and ros-melodic-qt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337030/qt-5-for-ros-melodic/) by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Needed to make some changes to make the old Qt4 ROS Kinetic GUI compile with Qt5 ROS Melodic. These were:

- Renaming the QtGui include to QtWidget
- package.xml according to: https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler/blob/master/package.xml#L27-L31
- CMakeLists according to: https://gist.github.com/facontidavide/b397b64e35cf8284382009ab6ad959f8

It's now using only "non-ROS" Qt libraries.

I made a package template here: https://github.com/jstiefel/qt5_ros_melodic_gui

---

Originally posted by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) with karma: 151 on 2019-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PanMav](https://answers.ros.org/users/51938/panmav/) on 2020-02-20**:
Thank you very much! Using the CMake.txt file from your Github repo help us a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have create this template. Hope that will help.
https://github.com/alexspirou/ROS_Melodic_Qt_GUI_Template

---

Originally posted by [alexspi13](https://answers.ros.org/users/57492/alexspi13/) with karma: 36 on 2021-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1